# Chrome not displaying Javascript createElement div correctly?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, createelement

I have the following legacy code creating a popup "autocomplete" box under a form input, using results returned from an AJAX call.  This code works fine in Firefox 6 and IE9 - it pops up a little div (styling is what Chrome shows in Developer Tools):

```
<div id="theDiv" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 21px; border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; border-top-color: green; border-right-color: green; border-bottom-color: green; border-left-color: green; border-top-width: 2px; border-right-width: 2px; border-bottom-width: 2px; border-left-width: 2px; border-image: initial; background-color: white; z-index: 1; visibility: hidden; "><div style="visibility: visible; ">[...autocomplete text here...]</div></div>
```

I can see this `<div>` in FF and IE, but Chrome displays a `<div>` that appears to be collapsed down to its borders.  Oddly, if I set a breakpoint using Developer Tools in the javascript code below at the `this.oDiv.style.visibility = "visible";` line, Chrome creates the `<div>` and shows it with the collapsed-down-to-borders size, but if I switch to the Elements tab in Developer Tools to try to see why, Chrome seems to recalculate something and my `<div>` suddenly appears and is correctly displayed.  If I refresh, things are broken again.

Is this a Chrome bug, or is there something wrong with my code?

The relevant code:

```
AutoComplete.prototype.onchange = function()
{
    // clear the popup-div.
    while ( this.oDiv.hasChildNodes() )
        this.oDiv.removeChild(this.oDiv.firstChild);

    // get all the matching strings from the AutoCompleteDB
    var aStr = new Array();
    this.db.getStrings("", "", aStr);

    // add each string to the popup-div
    var i, n = aStr.length;
    for ( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        var iDiv = document.createElement('div');

        var myText = document.createTextNode(aStr[i]);          
        iDiv.appendChild(myText);       

        iDiv.FormName = this.FormName;

        iDiv.onmousedown = AutoComplete.prototype.onDivMouseDown;
        iDiv.onmouseover = AutoComplete.prototype.onDivMouseOver;
        iDiv.onmouseout = AutoComplete.prototype.onDivMouseOut;
        iDiv.AutoComplete = this;
        iDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
        this.oDiv.appendChild(iDiv);

    }
    this.oDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like "theDiv" is absolutely positioned, so to be absolutely sure :) you need to specify not only its top and left but also right and bottom (or width and height.) Please see [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width) for more details on the element rendering in your case.

Comment: According to the w3.org link you gave me, I should be able to specify auto for width/right and the browser will solve for the width?   "3. 'width' and 'right' are 'auto' and 'left' is not 'auto', then the width is shrink-to-fit . Then solve for 'right'"  Chrome ignores the width:auto; right:auto; styling, or at least no difference. I still get a 1-pixel block in Chrome and in Firefox/IE the box is sized to the text it contains either way.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is what you need. But I had a similar issue. I was dynamically adding input boxes on my page on a button click event.
When the input boxes were not getting added on button click event in Chrome my script tag was as follows :

```
<script type="text/x-javascript" language="javascript">
```

Notice that the type is **text/x-javascript** .
And then I changed it to **text/javascript** and it worked then.
I just solved this issue so don't know the difference between the two types.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it's not the same issue.  In my case, the element was being added but the sizing was incorrect (showing up as literally a 1-pixel block, despite the content being visible via Chrome's Developer Tools).